# Prestashop, in .tpl, how to use smarty variable in <script content?

Tags: javascript, smarty, prestashop

I wish to use a smarty variable in my javascript, but I'm not unable to do this ><'

My current code but generate an error =>

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var title = document.title;
var height1 = {$mysmartyvariable1};
var height2 = {$mysmartyvariable2};
if (title == 'index')
{ var height = height1; }
else { var height = height2; };

$(document).on("scroll",function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop()>height){
        $("#nav").removeClass("navfull").addClass("navsmall");
    } else{
        $("#nav").removeClass("navsmall").addClass("navfull");
    }
});
</script>
```

So how I can add mysmartyvariable1 in this script section ?

#

Thanks Allan Nienhuis the correct code is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var title = document.title;
var height1 = {$mysmartyvariable1};
var height2 = {$mysmartyvariable2};
{literal}
if (title == 'index')
{ var height = height1; }
else { var height = height2; };

$(document).on("scroll",function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop()>height){
        $("#nav").removeClass("navfull").addClass("navsmall");
    } else{
        $("#nav").removeClass("navsmall").addClass("navfull");
    }
});
{/literal}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems I see with your code.

1) you have not put {} brackets around $mysmartyvariable2.  This will assign 'undefined' to height2 as smarty will not process this variable at all, and the javascript variable named $mysmartyvariable2 is not defined.

2) you need to use {literal} {/literal} tags anytime you are embedding javascript which uses { } characters, so that smarty does not try to interpret the javascript {} characters as smarty syntax.

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.literal

In this case you can start the {literal} tag after the height2 declaration/assignment, as the previous lines SHOULD be interpreted by smarty, but the following lines should NOT be interpreted by smarty.

```
var height2 = {$mysmartyvariable2};
{literal}
if (title == 'index') 
  { //code here 
  }

// other code
{/literal}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the bracket for mysmartyvariable2, that's wasn't present in my final code.

Tried and that's don't work ...
You suggested me to use "height2 = {mysmartyvariable2};" ? that's not "var height2 = {mysmartyvariable2};" ?

Comment: About the {literal} I tried by added them before the first { of my code, so  juste afiter my var lines, and the closing {/literal} before the script tag, but without success

Comment: Sorry I missed the $ in the example. I will fix the example.  However the {literal} and {/literal} are absolutely required whenever you have { } characters in your template file that need to be rendered to your output html.  Please post the text of your attempt so that we can help debug it.

Comment: also, please post the actual error you're getting - you never mention the details of the error other than to say "but generate an error"

Comment: The error was the fact all javascript was unload in my page.

After your correction I adapted the code and that's ok :)
Thanks for your precious help.